# Blocking all "external packets"

Tags: networking

I use VPN from home to work with my company network. This is what I want to achieve:

- I don't want any packet with IP address outside this VPN network (or simpy, with IP outside private networks address range) to leave my computer. How can I do that?

So, the VPN is not really important. More precisely (and general), I want configure my network in such way, that no packet with IP destination address outside local network will leave my computer.

The **ideal solution** would be to route this "external packets" through my primary (raw) ISP connection and "local packets" through VPN connection. Is it possible?

---

UPDATE: My computer operates under Windows XP SP3 and I use 'built in' support for VPN in Win XP.

Comment: Which operating system are you on, which VPN software are you using?

Comment: What's the VPN software on the server side?  Have you verified that this isn't already how it works?  I know Cisco's VPN stuff supports split tunneling so unless the range is within the routed block(s) it will go over your local connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a lot of people do it this way.  Their local/home connections egress directly to the internet, and the network traffic for their company network goes over the VPN.  You need to uncheck the VPN setting  "use the default gateway on remote network". On the General Tab of the VPN connection > TCP/IP settings.

Comment: +1 Greg. I believe this is called 'split tunneling'.